# Spring Mvc: MyWebApplicationInitializer.onStartUp is never called. Intellij + Tomcat 10

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat10

I am mostly a Node.js developer and having a tough time figuring this out.
`Index.jsp` works and delivers the html content `http://localhost:8080/SpringNoBootMvcDemo`

However, `http://localhost:8080/SpringNoBootMvcDemo/hello` says

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

I understand `WebApplicationInitializer` is a replacement for `web.xml`. I am using Intellij and on running on the project on `Tomcat`, `HELLO` is never printed. I believe this means `MyWebApplicationInitializer` is never loaded and `onStartup` is never called. I have been reading on this and even tried `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletIntializer`. That didn't help either.

```
package com.test;
import javax.servlet.*;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class MyWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

        System.out.println("HELLO");
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
                container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

Dispatcher Config

```
package com.test;

import com.test.MyBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class DispatcherConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        // instantiate, configure and return bean ...
        return new MyBean();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package com.test;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import javax.inject.Inject;

//@RequestMapping("/hey")
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Inject
    private MyBean bean;

    @RequestMapping(value= "/hello", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("HEY THERE!");
        this.bean.printSomething();
    }

}
```

Folder Structure
[image]

Comment: Do you try http://localhost:8080/hello ?

Comment: @Cheatr01 yes. That says `Not Found` too. I think `MyWebApplicationInitializer` is not loaded at all because I can't see the `HELLO` printed to the console.

Comment: Is there some reason for you don't use SpringBoot? Raw Spring is dificult for good setup. We use SpringBoot because of it. Use some SpringBoot tutorial for building REST api or this tutorial for build jsp web app: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp

Comment: @Cheatr01 I was able to setup a spring boot rest api successfully. But I wanted to get into the depth of how things work with Spring. But I guess there's not many useful tutorials on Spring anymore since the evolution of Spring Boot.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. :-) I recommende Spring in action for this.

Comment: @Cheatr01 I have switched back to Spring Boot again. Exploring Security and stuff. The official documentation for that too is equally incomplete or not adequate. Would you be willing to connect somewhere and help me as I continue exploring?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251826/discussion-between-mathews-mathai-and-cheatr01).